# Check for element in an array in Github action script

Tags: github, github-actions

I have two arrays defined in a Github action. Target is to check in which array a given element exists.

`Problem:` When using `contains` function, Github action seems to compare substrings even in case of array. While [this](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#contains) documentation seems to say that it is only the case when searching within string.

My code looks like below:

```
name: My action

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
        JUICE: |
          [
            "apple-juice",
            "orange-juice"
          ]
        FRUIT: |
          [
            "apple",
            "orange"
          ]
          

    - name: check juice
      if: contains(env.JUICE, 'apple')
      run: |
        echo "Found Juice"

    - name: check fruit
      if: contains(env.FRUIT, 'apple')
      run: |
        echo "Found Fruit"
```

`Output:` Both `check juice` and `check fruit` steps are getting executed. While I expect only `check fruit` to run.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to search for an item with bash array

```
name: array check test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
        JUICE: |
          (
            "apple-juice"
            "orange-juice"
          )

    steps:
    - name: check juice with bash
      run: |
          array=${{ env.JUICE }}
          for item in ${array[*]}
          do
            if [[ "$item" == "apple" ]]; then
              echo "Found Juice"
            fi
            if [[ "$item" == "apple-juice" ]]; then
              echo "Found Juice Full Name"
            fi
          done
```

output:
`Found Juice Full Name`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if: contains(fromJSON(env.JUICE), 'apple')
```